# How build and deliver patches for Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, patch

In the context of an RCP application I want to deliver to my customers a patch. This patch has modification in only one of my plugin included in one of my feature.

How should I build the patch and what will be the patch's content ?
How can I deliver this patch to my end users, through a zip file, an update site ?

Can you point me to any link on the subject ?

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deliver your patch as Feature Patch.

See [this](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/patching-features-with-p2.html) blog post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems this concerns patching the plateform itself and not custom RCP plugins.

Comment: @Manuel, I think they're same. Eclipse platform itself is the RCP applicaion, and is consist of plug-ins.