# How update Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In the context of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243685/how-build-and-deliver-patches-for-eclipse-rcp-application) I am wondering if it's possible to update a feature included in my RCP product (based on feature) without incrementing the RCP product version ?

Let's say I have the following RCP application

com.my.company.myproduct 1.0.0 including

- org.eclipse.rcp 3.5.0
- com.my.company.myproduct.feature1 1.0.0
- com.my.company.myproduct.feature2 1.0.0

My question is, can I increment, export and of course install (in the 1.0.0 environment) a new version of com.my.company.myproduct.feature2 (1.1.0 for example) whitout incrementing the product version number ?

I want to know this because it will avoid to have to provide a big (> 50 mega bytes) patch to my customers.

Comment: How to manage your product? Using p2 or classic update manager?

Comment: My product is managed with p2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly of all, you deploy your product into p2 repository. The top and root IU is com.my.company.myproduct_1.0.0. It consists of org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0 and com.my.company.feature_1.0.0.

Then your features have updates, so you can release com.my.company.myproduct to 1.1.0. It consists of org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0 and com.my.company.feature_1.1.0. It also should be deploied as p2 repository. However you can remove all the artifacts of org.eclipse.rcp(the feature and plug-in jars of org.eclipse.rcp) from the repository to reduce the size.

It's a cumulative repository, it can't be installed into a clean environment. However it could be installed on existing your product 1.0.0. P2 has the capability to just update the features that have the newer version.

**Update:**

If you reuse the UI of eclipse itself, the update repository should have higher version of your product to make the 'Install New Software'/update dialog of Eclipse show the newer version of your product.

If you use p2 API to install the update, the higher version of product is not necessary. But the original of your product(1.0.0) must depend on the version range of your feature. For example, com.my.company.myproduct_1.0.0 depends on com.my.company.feature from 1.0.0(include) to 2.0.0 (exclude).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I I got what you said, I MUST increment the product number but I can provide a new clean repository containing only the things that changed: am I right ? In this case p2 is clever enough to reuse the existing features and plugin about org.eclipse.rcp that didn't changed ?

Comment: Of course, p2 is clever enough not to update the non-changed features and plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

There is the good strating point and tutorial.

Tutorial: p2 updates for Eclipse RCP applications:
http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/p2_updates_tutorial_36